# Have the UK Conservatives lost the working majority and if so, what does this mean?

Tags: united-kingdom, parliament

The Conservatives in the UK are in a confidence and supply arrangement with the DUP in order to have a working majority in Parliament.

Yesterday, three Conservatives left the party to become independent, which means that they have 314 + 10 DUP, which is 324 out of 650.

Does this mean that they have lost the working majority and what does it mean if they have? Or is there any impact if/when they do?

The Government has a [page showing current parliamentary breakdown](https://www.parliament.uk/mps-lords-and-offices/mps/current-state-of-the-parties/).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Not yet. Because Sinn Fein hold 7 seats, but they refuse to take their seats in the House of Commons. By tradition, the Speaker of the house doesn't vote.So in practice there are 642 votes in the Commons. That means that 322 votes are needed for a working majority in practice, which the government still has (with the DUP's support).

At the time of writing the seat of Newport West is vacant after the recent death of the MP Paul Flynn (Labour) on 17th Feb 2019; he has been MP for that seat since 1987, so it can be regarded as a reasonably safe Labour seat in the upcoming by-election. This lowers the majority threshold to 321 seats until the vacant seat is filled.

There is no immediate impact if they do fall below that threshold though. The only way it matters is if the government loses a vote of no confidence. It is not certain that the ex -Tory members who have joined The Independent Group would all necessarily vote against the government in a no confidence motion.

Comment: If we’re accounting for the Speaker, we need also to count the Deputy Speakers (one Conservative, two Labour) who also don’t vote. And no, it’s not a coincidence that the party makeup of the Deputy Speakers, combined with the Speaker (who used to be a Conservative) cancels out any Government/Opposition imbalance.

Comment: So I make it 638 voting Members, currently, with the threshold for a majority therefore being 320. But also Eleanor Laing, as a Deputy Speaker (technically First Deputy Chairman of Ways and Means) needing to be taken off any count of the (effective) number of Conservative MPs.

Comment: For the time being the number of MPs able to vote is reduced by one more - Fiona Onasanya is unable to vote whilst she is in prison

Comment: [This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_MPs_elected_in_the_2017_United_Kingdom_general_election) has a breakdown of the numbers. It currently also comes out with a number of 638 voting MPs.

Comment: *"There is no immediate impact if they do fall below that threshold though. The only way it matters is if the government loses a vote of no confidence."* - A government can retain the confidence of the house whilst still finding it difficult to pass laws (e.g. the recent Brexit defeat). If they fall below the threshold, in spite of being able to pass a no confidence vote, there would be an immediate impact in that their confidence and supply arrangement with the DUP would no longer be sufficient and they would have to negotiate a new arrangement involving additional MPs.

Comment: Also worth mentioned that the Tories who did leave have all said they would support the government in most things, just not on a no-deal brexit.

Comment: By convention if a casting vote is required from the Speaker, they will not vote along party lines but according to [Speaker Denison's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speaker_Denison%27s_rule).

Comment: Various comments about Sinn Féin deleted. This is not the place to discuss the political positions, methods and the sources of funding for Sinn Féin. All that matters about them for this question and answer is that they do not take their seats in the House of Commons. Everything else that might be interesting about Sinn Féin is material for another question.

Comment: @stuart10 Does imprisonment prevent voting? As I vaguely understand it, American representatives are granted protections to always be able to vote, even if they're potentially spending the rest of their day in jail, as long as they hold the seat. I always assumed that was an inherited/adopted practice from the UK... I guess not.

Comment: @mbrig, the British convention is that an MP who is sentenced to imprisonment should resign their seat. However, note the choice of the word *convention*.

Comment: @mbrig Normally an MP is required to physically walk through the relevant lobby (aye/no) to vote. For seriously ill MPs an exception is normally made whereby they are 'nodded through' - their vote is counted if they are on the parliamentary estate (i.e. in an ambulance in the car park). There is currently no provision for proxy or remote voting, though it is being discussed in the context of new parents on maternity/paternity leave. Even then, I doubt it would be extended to imprisoned MPs

Answer (score 8):

At the time of writing, the [state of the parties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_MPs_elected_in_the_2017_United_Kingdom_general_election) ([alt source](https://www.parliament.uk/mps-lords-and-offices/mps/current-state-of-the-parties/))as it affects this calculation is:

- Conservative: 314
- DUP: 10
- Labour: 247
- Sinn Fein: 7
- The Speaker: 1
- Vacant: 1
- Everyone else: 70
- TOTAL: 650

However, the 3 Deputy Speakers - of whom 1 is Conservative and 2 are Labour - don't vote. Sinn Fein don't take their seats, so are also unable to vote. With the speaker and one vacancy, this reduces the number of voting MPs to 638.

This makes the number of votes required for a majority to be half of this plus one, i.e. 320.

The Government are in a confidence & supply agreement with the DUP, so in the event of another confidence vote, the number of Government votes available is 314 (Con MPs) - 1 (Deputy Speaker) + 10 (DUP MPs) = 323.

The number of Opposition votes available is 247 (Lab MPs) - 2 (Deputy Speakers) + 70 (everyone else, apart from Sinn Fein) = 315.

Hence the Government, in theory, have a majority of 8.

However, for non-confidence & supply votes, these numbers change to 313 and 325, leaving the Government short by 12 votes. And indeed, they have lost a number of votes recently - not merely because of these numbers, but also because, on Brexit issues, a number of Conservative MPs have not voted with the Government.

Comment: However, a splinter group with (as yet) no organization, no manifesto except being "agin the guvment" or "agin Corbyn", and no significant funding, would be on a suicide mission if it forced a general election through a no confidence vote right now. Not all the "rebels" are popular in their own constituencies and there is no guarantee they would be re-elected if they stood as independent candidates.